# Set picker values by tapping anywhere outside of a popup view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uipickerview

Currently have a popup view which sets 3 picker values by tapping on the SET button:
[image: Current SET button]

However, I want to remove the SET button altogether, and have the picker values set upon tapping outside of the popup, which in turn hides the popup.

Here is the current code:

```
    // function for selecting picker values
func pickerDidSet() {
        let focusPeriodChoice = focusPeriodDataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        let breakPeriodChoice = breakPeriodDataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
        let repeatCountChoice = repeatCountDataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]

        persistPickerChoice(focusPeriodChoice, dataType: .focusPeriod)
        persistPickerChoice(breakPeriodChoice, dataType: .breakPeriod)
        persistPickerChoice(repeatCountChoice, dataType: .repeatCount)

        timerSummaryLabel.text = "\(focusPeriodChoice)m • \(breakPeriodChoice)m • \(repeatCountChoice)x"

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { self.pickerContainerView.alpha = 0.0 }, completion: { finished in
            self.pickerContainerView.isHidden = true
        })
    }

// Open popup, by tapping gear icon
    @IBAction func openSettings(_ sender: Any) {
        pickerView.selectRow(pickerChoiceIndex(forDataType: .focusPeriod), inComponent: 0, animated: false)
        pickerView.selectRow(pickerChoiceIndex(forDataType: .breakPeriod), inComponent: 1, animated: false)
        pickerView.selectRow(pickerChoiceIndex(forDataType: .repeatCount), inComponent: 2, animated: false)

        self.pickerContainerView.isHidden = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.pickerContainerView.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }

// Once pickers have been set, display the summary
private func configureSummaryLabel() {
        let focusPeriodChoice = pickerChoice(forDataType: .focusPeriod)
        let breakPeriodChoice = pickerChoice(forDataType: .breakPeriod)
        let repeatCountChoice = pickerChoice(forDataType: .repeatCount)

        timerSummaryLabel.text = "\(focusPeriodChoice)m • \(breakPeriodChoice)m • \(repeatCountChoice)x"
    }

// Setting the picker “SET” button
private func addPickerSetButton(atX x: CGFloat, centerY: CGFloat) {
        pickerSetButton.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: 40, height: 20)
        pickerSetButton.center = CGPoint(x: pickerSetButton.center.x, y: centerY)
        pickerSetButton.setTitle("SET", for: .normal)
        pickerSetButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        pickerSetButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: .highlighted)
        pickerSetButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
        pickerSetButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerDidSet), for: .touchUpInside)
        pickerHeaderView.addSubview(pickerSetButton)
    }
```

Comment: Is your Popup is just a view or a viewController that you are presenting?

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas I believe its a view within a viewController: `class FocusHomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let pickerTitles = ["FOCUS", "BREAK", "CYCLES"] ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Previous Black View is you default view of ViewController then all you need is to implemented below method.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // Check that the touched view is your background view
        if touches.first?.view == self.view {
            // Do What Every You want to do
        }
}
```

**Detail**
Every `ViewController` has a default `view` object. As in your case the black overlay displaying behind your popup seems like the default view of that view controller. If that black overlay is not your default view then create and `IBOutlet` of that view which is black opacified in color. And then in the above method where you are check that which view is touch check that if touched view is your black view or not.
Suppose you black view's `IBOutlet` is `backgroundView` then the above check will be something like this.

```
if touches.first?.view == self.backgroundView {
    //It means you have touched outside the pop and out side the pop there is only your backgroundView.
    //Here you should do exactly the same which you were doing when `SET` button was clicked.

}
```

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate more... for example what does the `// Check that the touched view is your background view` look like? And how can I integrate this with the code I provided in the post. I picked up this project and am just a beginner with iOS.

Comment: I am implementing your suggestion. See my edit above. I am getting an error for the addTarget function.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the black background _is_ the default viewController whereas the pickerContainerView is an @IBOutlet.

Comment: That black view which covers the entire screen with blackish overly. Container might be the view having same size of picker view

Comment: Thanks, got it solved! I just had to add the pickerDidSet function to your code. However, there is one issue... you see that Red circle, it's a button. And if user taps on it while the IBOutlet is on top, it fires, without firing the touchesBegan code. So how can I make it first run touchesBegan and then fire the button.

Comment: I have posted an other answer for this Question.

Answer (score 1):

`touchesBegan` method didn't work if touched object is a button so as per you logic.
You need to check if the PickerView is visible then disable it instead of firing the other feature of that button.

**Example.**

Create a boolean variable named `isPickerViewVisible` in your class and when picker view is going to visible make it true and when picker view is getting hide just make it false. There might be an IBAction for that red button.

```
@IBAction didTapButton(_ sender: Any){
    //Here you need to check if pickerView is open then disable it. I don't know what logic you have implemented to show picker view.
    if isPickerViewVisible {
        self.pickerDidSet()
    }else {
        //Here you should do the task that you do on clicking this button.
    }
}
```